# why i am getting field error in python django when ia going to develop project

Tags: python

I am developing a blog project using python django framework where I am getting

> FieldError at /2019/05/10/india-movie-information-rulz/ Cannot resolve
>   keyword 'publish_year' into field. Choices are: author, author_id,
>   body, created, id, publish, slug, status,

Comment: my urls is  urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.postlistview),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_detail_view,name='post_detail'),
    ]

Comment: my views is like from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from blog.models import Post


def postlistview(request):
    postlist=Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,'blog/postlist.html',{'postlist':postlist})
def post_detail_view(request,year,month,day,post):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post,slug=post,
                            status='published',
                            publish_year=year,
                            publish_month=month,
                            publish_day=day)
    return render(request,'blog/postdetail.html',{'post':post})

Answer (score 0):

When We are filtering by sql functions, named [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) (In this example "year") we use two underscores.
So we do like `.filter(publish__year=sth)` and not `.filter(publish_year=sth)`.
In the first case the year here will be converted to `year(publish)` in sql.
but in second case the publish_year will be parsed as property of your model.